# expert (early) musketmen vs expert archers, who wins?

Tags: warfare, weapons, hard-science, history

I have two sides in a conflict, one utilizing a larger, highly trained, military of soldiers and archers.  This side is invading (crossing a large body of water, with appropriate logistical hurdles implied) another side which is utilizing an equivlent of muskets but currently has a much smaller standing army.

I want to ensure the musket side is at a disadvantage in the early conflict, but I want the battle to be close.  To do this I need to get a better idea of how close muskets are to bow & arrows, in particular, to get an idea of how much I need to skew numeric superiority either way to give the correct level of advantage between the two sides.

So, for example, imagine a fight with 1000 soldiers on both sides.  One side is wielding early muskets, about the strength of muskets Europe had when setting up colonies on the New World.  The other side has well crafted bow and arrows.  Both sides are experienced and well trained with good leadership.  Both sides are wearing little if any armor. Which side has the advantage?  How significant is this advantage? Finally, how drastically does this change if I the archers are switch with combined arms with both archers and swordsmen (no cavalry) attacking the musketeers?

At first glance one may say muskets, but I'm not certain.  My understanding is that early muskets main advantage was logistical, you could train up rank amateurs to competence in a fraction the time it took to develop a good bowman; and it was logistically easier to provide arms for rifles.  I'm not certain that in combat muskets were actually superior weapons if logistics and training were not a factor.

I'm looking for historic information: I want this to be as factually accurate as possible. Ideally I'd like answers only from those with actual knowledge about the weapons on historic battles to back their answer with.

Comment: Archers, They could fire quicker and 1 arrow is roughly as dangerous as 1 musket ball.

Comment: Asking "Who would win in a fight?" isn't asking about building a world.

Comment: @sphennings I have two sides in a world, one with access to each type of weaponry.  To decide how battles will happen in this world I need to know who has supperior weaponry.  I'm going to adjust the size of the two sides and some other options to keep them roughly equal, with the musketeers at a slight disadvantage; but again I need to know how significant the difference in strength is to better identify this.

Comment: I figure this is off topic as it doesn't really focus on any aspect of building a world.

Comment: The fire rate of a musket is about 2-3 rounds per minute, whereas a skilled archer can shoot 10 arrows a minute comfortably and accurately.

Comment: The big advantage of early firearms vs. bows (and crossbows, don't forget crossbows) was that they required much less training. Making a good longbowman was a lifetime exercise; making a decent arquebusier was a matter of a few weeks of instruction. A secondary advantage was that at very close ranges, say less than 50 meters or so, a coordinated musket volley had (usually) more deadly effect than a volley of arrows or bolts. A massive disadvantage of early firearms was that you could not aim for a specific target -- they were fired in a volley in the general direction of the enemy.

Comment: Muskets were useful because they were faster to learn how to use and shoot than a bow. They were not about power, but ease of use - it was easier to put a lot more people firing muskets with little training than it was to train bowmen. Some modern bows are a superior weapon even against some modern firearms - they aren't widely used anymore because of the lack of convenience compared to firearms. So, if you have more musketeers than archers, _maybe_ the musketeers have a chance. Otherwise? Eh, they're dead.

Comment: @AlexP Your comment hit the question just as I was typing mine. We thought almost the same thing.

Comment: Another big advantage of the muskets was the logistical tail.  A musketeer could fire a shot every 40 seconds. (British standard during the Napoleonic wars) Powder and ball took up less room than a film can or small pill bottle.  An archer could fire 12 arrows a minute for several minutes at a time.  A musketeer could carry a battle's worth of ammo with him easily.  A bowman could not. Arrows warped if they got wet.  It was a lot easier to keep powder dry than to keep arrows dry.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford: The Napoleonic wars were very very far from the age of primitive firearms. Think more of the [Long Turkish War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Turkish_War) or the [Thirty Years' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War). Before that, man-portable firearms were much too imprecise and fussy to be used in war on any kind of large scale.

Comment: It took like, 300 years before guns fully replaced other forms of warfare. Hands down, in early days, your archers win. Loading a musket takes more time than loading and firing an arrow. On the first volley, you would take out more people most likely with a musket (but the range would be shorter if you want accuracy and real power) but AFTER that, your archers win. If you're talking a wall of people then, accuracy isn't as much a thing.

Comment: It's also a question of matchlock (~15th century), wheellock (~16th century), flintlock(17th century)... just to name on very imporatant development that changed the effectiveness and reliability of early firearms dramatically.

Comment: There's a series of videogames under the collective name of [Total War](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_War_(series)) - I'd recommend getting Shogun 2 Total War and playing around setting up armies of bowmen and riflemen against each other. The series is praised for historic accuracy, so it should be able to provide some good guesstimates. It will also show you the drastically different ways of fighting that make one thing superior in certain situations.

Comment: @Adwaenyth The question pretty much makes it clear that we are referring to very primitive types of musket - the ones that were unable to phase out bows until further development on the technology was made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Factors *for* the use of black powder weapons

1. Penetrating power. The arquebus, especially, was far more effective at penetrating plate armor. In fact, plate armor fell out of use because of the arquebus. And this power wasn't reliant on the archer's strength. While the crossbow also didn't rely on the archer's strength, they weren't as powerful as the arquebus.
2. Training time. It took less training to bring up a unit of arquebusiers than an effective unit of archers. Archers take years to become profficient, vs. months for arquebusiers.
3. Rate of fire. The arquebus reload time was slower than a bow, yes. But it was faster than crossbows of the time, at about 60 seconds to reload.
4. Ammunition. An arquebusier could carry more shot and powder than an archer could carry arrows.
5. Range. Accounts vary, but it appears that a volley of arquebusier shots could out-distance bows in many cases. Though accounts vary and argue over accuracy at long ranges, so no consensus can be confirmed.
6. Noise. I don't find data for this, but I imagine that the first time a cavalry charge comes up against the noise of powder weapons, horses would not take kindly to this. I don't know how long it took to retrain men and horses to ignore the loud report of powder weapons, but there probably was at least some time involved.
7. Smoke. Black powder weapons produce a great deal of smoke, which obscures the battlefield, hindering your enemy's forces.

### Factors *against* the use of black powder weapons

1. Rain and humidity. While bows and bowstrings won't last long in bad weather, an arquebusier literally could not fire in the rain, and even high humidity could impact their powder. Improper storage causes powder to age quickly relative to bows and arrows.
2. Danger to the user. An arquebus could blow up in the arquebusier's face. Especially if a panicked shooter failed to manage his weapon carefully.
3. Rate of fire. Again, slower than an archer at 30-60 seconds between shots.
4. Smoke. Black powder weapons produce a great deal of smoke, which obscures the battlefield, hindering your own forces.

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquebus#History) for much of the above, particularly the section comparing to bows.)

### History decided

It took a while. The first handgun appeared in European literature in 1326. Cavalry wasn't supplanted by infantry until the advent of the bayonet in the 1690s. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_modern_warfare#Firearms))

Clearly, the initial gunpowder technology wasn't sufficiently superior to existing methods of warfare to affect a [sea change](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sea%20change) in warfare. Instead, we see a gradual transition from bows and cavalry to musket infantry. This indicates that the technology required some refinement and improvement over time. During this period, the strategists and tacticians of the day also had to learn how to *best* use this new tool.

Comment: When you say the arquebus has a greater range are you factoring in the ability to angle an arrow at a 45 degree angel to increase it's effective range?  Also, was smoke really a disadvantage, I would imagine it hindered the enemies ability to aim as much as your own, so I would have figured the smoke would work out to a neutral effect in total, not a disadvantage?

Comment: @dsollen the link I included (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquebus#History) under "comparison to bows" 1st paragraph discusses range at length.

Answer (score 7):

The maximum range of a [longbow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_longbow#Range) isn't a hard and fast figure recorded historically, but the useful range is quoted here between 200 and 400 yards. This will be highly reliant on the quality of the bow and the training received by the bowman.

A standard smoothbore [musket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Bess#The_Land_Pattern_Muskets) could have an "effective" range of up to 175 yards but this ignores some important points on its own. A smoothbore rifle's accuracy was utterly nil for any kind of sharpshooting at virtually any range, and one rifleman on his own couldn't really be counted on to hit a target in the same way you could with a rifled weapon today. Muskets were fired *en masse* in a formation towards an enemy formation, with the sheer volume of fire ensuring a certain percentage of hits.

Not that bows weren't fired *en masse* for the same effect, but they are far less of a random shot in practiced hands. The big tell in this comparison is that while muskets had an effective range near the range at which bows were used, musket formations were instructed not to shoot until they were at a range of **just 50 yards**. Or famously at Bunker Hill, "til you see the whites of their eyes."

Comment: En Masse use especially, when shooting beyond 200 yards with a bow. You usually have a very high projectile trajectory - so high actually, that aiming at a specific target is next to impossible and you're left with "throw enough at it and some will hit". That was the basic military doctrine up until World War I - where they learned the hard way that it isn't any longer.

Comment: @Adwaenyth The thing was that, while for bows that range was around 200 yards, for early muskets that range was like 1̶0̶ ̶f̶e̶e̶t̶  much shorter.

Comment: @Ross - So, in other words, the musketeers have no chance if their weapons are the only deciding factor?

Comment: @T.Sar If we're on a flat plain, I see no problem for the archers to move and shoot more often & more comfortably. I think they will need to take a higher volume of "shots" to get the job done though, compared to a musketball which I think generally caused more lethal wounds.

Comment: @T.Sar in direct fire, comparing a modern compound bow and a "modern" musket, they are surprisingly similar in accuracy. In competition shooting, the musket still uses a slightly smaller target size compared to the bow at similar distance. - That in terms of accuracy form an active competition shooter (who has also tested both weapon types).

Comment: @Adwaenyth have you ever competed with smoothbore weapons? (that aren't shotguns...)

Comment: @Ross I fired the musket only in training, but a several times european champion trains in our district and I know what results he achieves with that thing. Actually it isn't that difficult to hit, it is however relying very much on powder and bullet being very carefully selected. ;)

Comment: @Adwaenyth Ross makes a very good point. The issue isn't comparing with modern "muskets", is comparing with the early, poorly made firearms from the referenced question. WWI was far beyond already from early colonial America, in Tech levels.

Comment: @T.Sar and in the late 15th and early 16th century no one ever thought about compensators, stabilizers or visual aids on an area denial weapon (aka the longbow) that was mostly used in indirect fire by then. The musket I'm talking about was designed before 1871 btw. ;)

Comment: When you cite max range are you consider a straight shot or an angled shot?  In warfare I'm pretty sure archers fired at (slightly less then) a 45 degree angle to maximize their range whie the enemy was at a distance.  Was that angle already factored into your calculation of range?

Comment: @dsollen I'm just borrowing Wiki figures but yes, I think there's no doubt the furthest shots are shot at an angle. An angled shot is still an aimed shot

Comment: @dsollen 200 yards would likely be something like a 15° angle, 400 more like a 35° angle with a strong bow. You literally never shoot that nowadays in competition shooting because it would be wildly inaccurate... which means to hit a target that is about a meter wide... on a battlefield it would still be accurate enough when there are a lot of people around. ;)

Comment: Yes, after closer reading the 400 yard shot is not well substantiated. I don't think many bowman would be asked to shoot further than 300.

Comment: This answer seems to compare the effective range of muskets against point targets to the maximum range of bows against area targets. Compare like terms, and Renaissance-era firearms beat out longbows both for effective range against a point target (sub-100yds for a longbow) and for maximum range against an area target (as far as 500yds for a musket). The inaccuracy of muskets is often exaggerated and in large part attributable to lack of training; you can read more about early firearm performance [here](https://sellsword.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/firearms/).

Answer (score 1):

With equal numbers, the archers would win. Muskets can't be aimed.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musket#Tactics
http://www.willegal.net/iron_brigade/musket.pdf
https://allthingsliberty.com/2013/07/the-inaccuracy-of-muskets/
The only real use of muskets was against massed infantry: even if the shooter missed his target, he'd hit the one next to him, or someone in the next line.

An expert archer could fire [one aimed shot every ten seconds](https://www.thoughtco.com/hundred-years-war-english-longbow-2361241)
 http://dankoboldt.com/medieval-versus-modern-archery/,
which is comparable to the four shots per minute of the musketeer, but with a better chance of hitting.

Comment: Yes, but are archers aiming?  My understanding is that in large warfare neither side aimed, they just fired in the general direction and hoped they hit something.  For archers it allowed for more arrows fired at a time  and greater range (if they aimed at a 45 degree angle)

Comment: @dsollen: Only when they're worried about the other party closing in. The point of archers was to thin out the enemy before they could get to melee range, at which point they would simply be sitting ducks. With musketeers on the other side, there's no such risk; they can take their time and pick their target at a greater effective range. Besides, arrows are bigger than musket shot, so each archer carries less ammunition than each musketeer. Best to make each shot count.

Answer (score 1):

At equal numbers the archers will generally win right through until WWII (the M1 was supposedly the first firearm to outclass a longbow for all the performance characteristics of range, firing rate, accuracy, *and* stopping power), but good archers have to be practically born to it, you can turn out a good musketeer in a week or two of intensive training. Musketeers beat archers because of weight of fire, you can have a lot more of them for the same training investment and they also have a denser formation presenting more firepower per length of front. Using ranked fire you can get the same firing rate out of a unit at a given length of front as well, you just need about three times as many gunners as you would archers. If you mean men-at-arms when you say "soldiers" that presents another issue because the fire from early muskets tended to bounce off plate armour making them almost invulnerable at range, their horses if they were riding as lancers not so much against volley fire but the men yes. Ammunition supply might actually be a decisive factor in the battle, if the musketeers run out of powder and shot, or more likely the fine priming powder, trying to deal to plate armoured foot soldiers at long range then it's going to go badly for them, just like it would for archers who get caught by heavy infantry.